# Next key view of NSTextView find bar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview, appkit

Suppose there is a window which has two `NSTextViews` in it, and each of them uses the `findBar`.

The problem is that after closing one find bar (finishing the finding) the cursor jumps to the other `textView`, i.e. the focus does not return the the `textView` for which the find operation originated.

Please, does anyone know how to make it return to the original view?

This is a screenshot of one simple setup:

[image]

Comment: Can you paste your code?So that it will be easy to identify the problem.

Comment: @HussainShabbir There is not much of a source code, it's basically just two textviews in Interface Builder / Xcode. See the edit for a screenshot.

Comment: Are using  single IBOutlet for both NSTextView ??

Comment: @HussainShabbir No, I just placed there the two textviews...

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the **[nextKeyView property](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSView/nextKeyView)** in StoryBoards (see image below) to assign where you want to the focus to "jump", otherwise, if you need to assign the **[nextKeyView property](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSView/nextKeyView)** programmatically (when the view is initialized), you can do so using the nextKeyView property available via the **[NSView class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/)**. Both methods are hinted at below:

#### 1. Assign the nextKeyView programmatically via this property

```
@property(assign) NSView *nextKeyView;
```

#### 2. Or you can assign the nextKeyView in storyboards

[image: Or you can assign the nextKeyView in storyboards]

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: Added update to my answer: if you choose to set the nextKeyView property programmatically, you assign the nextKeyView property during the view's initialization, not in a delegate method like I had previously mentioned.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! Yes, I know about `nextKeyView` property. The problem is, how to set it for `findbar` (NSTextFinder)? If I had access to Text Field, like your screenshot shows, that would be no problem. But the `findbar` creates the UI "implicitly" and I don't know how to "jump" from it to my textview. Have you tried it for `NSTextView` with "Find: Uses Bar", as in my screenshot?

Comment: I don't actually see your findbar in the screenshot, am I missing something?

Comment: The `findbar` shows-up only when you try to search in "live" application. That is, when you set up the UI hierarchy like the screenshot shows, run the program, hit cmd+f, then you can see the `findbar`...

Comment: Are you using any delegate methods to determine when the findbar has completed? At what point exactly are wanting the focus to return to the NSTextView?

Comment: To answer your first question, no. Is there anything like this? And the second one: when I finish the "finding", i.e. hit "esc" or click "Done", not sure if there are any other means of being done... See for example TextEdit.

Answer (score 1):

Set the [nextKeyView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSView/nextKeyView) property of the text field back to the original view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But how do I find the text field of find bar? I don't see it in Xcode and NSTextView docs apparently don't mention it either...

Comment: In the source list (left pane of the xcode view) click on you files called XIB. This is where you build your UI.

Comment: Yes, I'm there but I don't see the "text field". I have the scroll view, clipview and textview, I can check whether the textview uses the findbar. But where can I find the field, so I can link it back?

Comment: Finding it hard to follow this. Let's take it to chat. We can exchange some screenshot.

Comment: Are you here? I don't know how to create a chat with you, but I'm now in NSChat room...

Answer (score 1):

You can create the subclass of textview and mention the same inside your interface builder->Custom class and inside your custom textview class override the below method:-

```
-(BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: `NSTextView` returns `YES` by default.

Comment: Did you try using custom class??